# Set of points such that the distance is achieved by at least two geodesics is closed

Tags: riemannian-geometry

If $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and let $p\in M$. Define a function $$d^2:M\to \mathbb{R},~q\mapsto \mathrm{dist}^2(p,q).$$ Consider the set $$A=\text{Set of all points $q\in M$ such that the distance is achieved by at least two geodesics. }$$ I need to prove that the set $A$ is closed.

I tried to go by the sequence approach (as $M$ has a metric). Let $\{q_n\}$ be the points in $A$ and $q_n\to q$. I need to prove that $q\in A$. Now let $\gamma_n$  and $\eta_n$ be geodesics such that $$d(p,q_n)=l(\gamma_n)=l(\eta_n).$$ Now is it possible (or  a similar idea) to prove that limit of the two geodesics converge to the geodesic and as the length is a continuous function $$l(\gamma_n)\to l(\gamma),~~\text{and}~~ l(\eta_n)\to l(\eta),$$ which will prove that $q\in A$ and we are done.

Please tell me if this approach is valid or if any other approach I have to go through.

Comment: Where were you told that this subset is closed?

Comment: I guessed that the set where the geodesics are unique is open but that was somewhat hard to prove that is why tried to go through the closedness.

Comment: This subset is not closed in general. See for example Figure 13 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid. The set of limit points of your set may consist of points, conjugate to $p$, where there is only one minimizing geodesics. Your argument is incorrect as the two limit geodesics may be the same.

Comment: @Raziel,  Sorry, I didn't get you. Isn't the set $A$ is the cut-locus, which is closed?

Comment: No, the cut locus in Riemannian geometry *can* be defined as the closure of your set. But $A$ is not closed in general. Again, see the example of the ellipsoid.

Comment: @Raziel, Then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547834/the-set-a-is-open is also false, as it is the complement of the set $A$.

Comment: That's correct.